# Is there any option for mirror imaging in video editing software?

Tags: video, video-editor

I recently encountered this video:

I really like the presentation of that person in the video. I guess he has a glass screen infront of the him and he is writing it. But is he writing it backward? Or is it an editing effect? I mean, any option for mirror imaging the video?

Comment: Related question: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/video-with-person-writing-on-glass-effect

Comment: Comments on that video say the actor is right-handed in other videos, so this one is flipped horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would matter that much other than for the actor writing, easier if (s)he doesn't have to think about reverse-writing. The flipping effect is a one-click effect and wouldn't require much in terms of hardware, software or brain-power.

What editing software are you using - the effect should be easy to find in any way. It might not even be an effect as such but rather a transform feature but it would help if the editor was brought out.

I doubt that your editor DOESN'T have this effect but in the strange case where it doesn't, you can also try setting the width of the image to -100%, that works on some editors. But I'm pretty sure there is a flip.horizontal effect somewhere.